# How to determine a correct interpolation technique for discount factor curves?

Tags: interpolation

I think Log-Linear interpolation of discount factor curve is most preferred. I think this is due to the fact of not having any arbitrages in the forward rates. Can someone share some literature or some test cases where this is prominently evidenced and some supporting articles if any?

[image: Interest rate Scenarios]

Comment: Not an expert on yield curve interpolation, but in IV term structure and skew/smile, we commonly fit a curve to the points and use RMSE or MAE to check the goodness of fit.

Comment: Use log-cubic spline or log-linear. Typically Interbank curves are constructed with log-linear in the first 3 years where datapoints are dense and log-cubic spline at the longer end where data points are sparser. Eg. https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/c_curves.html#mixed-interpolation